I am not sure how to optimize retrofit with callback in kotlin, or how to remove the callback after its done
I am using callbacks in Kotlin, and I currently have the exact retrofit function returning result in the form of a callback as its used multiple times across different classes,the endpoints are different, but the calling structure is always the same
RetrofitInstance().UserAction("retrieveChatForUser",cuserData){ returnMessage->
            if(returnMessage.status==true) {
                val chatList = returnMessage.content as List<Any>
                adapter.setData(chatList)
            }
        }

and my common retrofit class it like this
class RetrofitInstance {

 fun UserAction(action:String, userData: UserData, toUserData: UserData?=null, returnCallback:(ReturnMessage)->Unit){
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(CommonVals.base_url)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
    val service: RestApiUser = retrofit.create(RestApiUser::class.java)
    val callAuth: Call<ReturnMessage> = service.authOraddUser(action, userData.username,userData.phonenumber,toUserData?.username)
    callAuth.enqueue(object : Callback<ReturnMessage> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ReturnMessage>, response: Response<ReturnMessage>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val post = response.body()
                post?.let { post->
                    Log.d("api","${action} ${post}")
                    returnCallback(post)
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("apierror", "${action} error ${response.code()}")
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ReturnMessage>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("apierror","${action} error ${t.message}")
        }
    })
}

private interface RestApiUser {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("{action}")
    fun authOraddUser(
        @Path("action") action:String,
        @Field("username") username: String?=null,
        @Field("password") password: String?=null,
        @Field("username2") username2: String?=null,
    ): Call<ReturnMessage>
}

}
I am currently not sure if the callbacks will be immediately removed after execution; if so I am not sure how to remove them after I receive the callback, as I want to make the class as an object so that I don't create multiple objects instances

Callbacks for a single fetch like this are automatically disposed when they are finished with. But you’re not currently exposing a way to cancel them early. And currently your RetrofitInstance class is kind of pointless. There’s not really any reason to create a class that has no properties and doesn’t implement interfaces.

You should not implement retrofit this way.
you can try this way
the first. let's create interface, let's say you have 2 different types of api
// Api user
public interface RestApiUser {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("{action}")
    fun authOraddUser(
        @Path("action") action: String,
        @Field("username") username: String? = null,
        @Field("password") password: String? = null,
        @Field("username2") username2: String? = null,
    ): Call<ReturnMessage>

    @POST("{logout}")
    fun logout(): Call<ReturnMessage>
}
//api chatting
public  interface RestApiChatting {
    @POST("{chatting}")
    fun chatting(
        @Path("chatting") action: String,
    ): Call<ReturnMessage>
}

After that, create a class to manage it
object ApiManager {

    val ApiUser = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.abc/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(RestApiUser::class.java)


    val ApiProfile = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.abc/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(RestApiChatting::class.java)
}

use it
fun userAction(
    action: String,
    userData: UserData,
    toUserData: UserData? = null,
    returnCallback: (ReturnMessage) -> Unit
) {
    val callAuth: Call<ReturnMessage> =
        ApiManager.ApiUser.authOraddUser(
            action,
            userData.username,
            userData.phonenumber,
            toUserData?.username
        )
    callAuth.enqueue(object : Callback<ReturnMessage> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ReturnMessage>, response: Response<ReturnMessage>) {
          returnCallback()
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ReturnMessage>, t: Throwable) {

        }
    })
}

This approach will ensure that only 1 object is created in the entire program.
it will not create multiple object instances
